# How to change the definition of word separators for the shell?

Tags: linux, terminal, shell

Is there a way to change the definition of the word separators in bash? This will allow me, for example, to do ctrl+w (delete previous word) at the end of this path:

> /some/path/of/some/file

and the effect will be that only "`file`" will be deleted, and not the whole path.

**edit**: to be more clear, word deletion is just one possible usage, but I'm interested in moving between words, etc. Also, I want to be able to configure underlines and other chars as separators, not only slash.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to redefine or bind anything. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to achieve the desired result.

See: http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/features_7.html

To move between words use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> for **b** ack and **f** orward. This will also take _ as a seperator.

Comment: And how do I delete the next word, move between words, etc?

Answer (score 0):

From [Is it possible to configure ctrl-w (delete word)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27927/is-it-possible-to-configure-ctrl-w-delete-word):

> You should be able to use Esc, then backspace to delete words delimited by slashes.
>
> You can change this by putting this in you .bashrc:
>
> ```
> bind '\C-f:unix-filename-rubout'
> ```
>
> Now use Ctrl+f to do what you want.

Comment: thanks! would upvote if I had enough rep. This partially answers my question (please see my edit).